# Indexer always getting stuck processing when using the admin GUI

Tags: magento-1.9, reindex, indexing

When completing a reindex via the admin GUI it always gets stuck and never completes. If I reindex via the command line it completes rather 3 minutes. Could anyone advise the best way to make the GUI work without getting stuck

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you start an indexing process, Magento writes out a lock file to the var/locks folder.

```
$ ls var/locks
index_process_1.lock    index_process_4.lock    index_process_7.lock
index_process_2.lock    index_process_5.lock    index_process_8.lock
index_process_3.lock    index_process_6.lock    index_process_9.lock
```

The lock file prevents another user from starting an indexing process. However, if the indexing request times out or fails before it can complete, the lock file will be left in a lock state. In `var/locks` folder delete the .lock file which was created.

This will be the first step in solving.

Also check if php execution time and memory limit are not the reason for indexing script not completing its execution.